# UnicodeDecodeError upon reading xls files

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to read in and extract information from many excel files in XLS format using python. When I run my code, I encounter the following Warnings and Error:

WARNING *** file size (89002) not 512 + multiple of sector size (512)

WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x20 in position 108: truncated data

What's funny is that once I open the file manually and then run the code, the code will execute just fine.

Since there are about 500 files in the folder, I'd like to find out the cause of the error so that I can automate the process without having to open every single file. Any help would be appreciated!

(Below is an example of the type of xls file)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2r8br0nblbbr0x/A1-1a105800.XLS?dl=1

```
data_year = 2007

path = 'C:/Users/hard1/Desktop/CRA/' + str(data_year)



filenames = []


#count = 0
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xls')):
    #print(filename)
    #count = count+1
    filenames.append(filename)
#print(count)









respondent_id = []
bank_name = []
loan_amount = []
state = []
year = []





for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)
#    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename, encoding_override="utf_16_le")

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)



    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)


    # Column M index is 
    msa_string = sheet.cell(2, 12).value 
    state_string = msa_string[len(msa_string)-2 : len(msa_string)]

    col_id = sheet.col_values(5)
    col_bank = sheet.col_values(0)
    col_loan = sheet.col_values(23)







    ### And then code that extracts information from the files follows
```

Comment: I get a 404 not found error when I look for the dropbox link. Also, is it the file that is 89002 bytes? I'd definitely link to that one. My initial guess of what's happening is that opening the file manually might decompress it, and opening the (temporary) decompressed file works okay.

Comment: I fixed the link - it should work now. And the size of the file is 97kb. I'm not quite sure whether the file gets decompressed when I manually open it.

Comment: @hard1009 link returns 404 again